# Insert multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've seen in many places a good approach to insert several rows in Oracle is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('aa', 'cc');
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('ww', 'dd');
```

But, in the case of a bulk insert of many rows, is that supposed to be good-performant, given that we're executing separated queries? What about the classic overhead problem in these cases of multi-querying (networking, parsing,...)?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed an inefficient way to insert into a table. The exact statements you illustrated could be replaced with

```
INSERT INTO mytable ("id", "name") 
  select 'val1', 'val2' from dual union all
  select 'aa'  , 'cc'   from dual union all
  select 'ww'  , 'dd'   from dual
;
```

Of course, if your table has more than two columns, the other columns will be `null` (or the default value for the column, if so defined).

Even better, the values you are inserting are already in a table of some sort - then you can use a single SELECT statement, perhaps with WHERE conditions, joins, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `INSERT ALL INTO` ([Documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php)).

```
INSERT ALL 
  INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
  INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('aa', 'cc')
  INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('aa', 'cc')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a Select, if you already have the dada in some SQL object,
but when exists the needing of insert a lot of information we can use another methods like send txt files and do the bulk insert, with 100,000 rows of plain text at this time (2016) isn't too much traveling for the 1gb network there's no problem.

check this:

[Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx)

[Bulk Import and Export of Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx)

Example of select insert:

```
Insert into Table
select id, column1, column2 from tempTable
```

It's faster than 
  INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
  INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('aa', 'cc')
  INTO mytable ("id", "name") VALUES ('aa', 'cc')

NOTE!!!!!!

SORRY!!!  you asking about ORACLE... I gues could be some like this for ORACLE